# In Mathematica, how to simplify expressions like a == +/- b into a^2 == b^2?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, simplify

In Mathematica, how can I simplify expressions like `a == b || a == -b` into `a^2 = b^2`?  Every function that I have tried (including Reduce, Simplify, and FullSimplify) does not do it.

Note that I want this to work for an arbitrary (polynomial) expressions `a` and `b`. As another example,

```
a == b || a == -b || a == i b || a == -i b
```

(for imaginary `i`) and

```
a^2 == b^2 || a^2 == -b^2
```

should both be simplified to `a^4 == b^4`.

**Note:** the solution should work at the logical level so as not to harm other unrelated logical cases. For example,

```
a == b || a == -b || c == d
```

should become

```
a^2 == b^2 || c == d.
```

Comment: your desired simplification is mathematically incorrect. In the above example I assume you want a^2==b^2, right?

Comment: Unless `a` is absolutely guaranteed to have absolute values of 1 or 0, that's not a simplification, but rather a new expression.  Try with values of 2 for `a` and `b`.  Using the absolute values works for real numbers, but not when extending it to the complex plane.

Comment: you can't, because a==+-b and a^2 == b are not equivalent. a==+-b and a^2==b^2 are.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries Yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Woodrow Douglass My math had a mistake.  Please see the new version.

Comment: Awww... Mr.W deleted his comment just when I found [this gem](http://i.imgur.com/QCF8Q.gif) to go with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Boolean expression can be converted to the algebraic form as follows:

```
In[18]:= (a == b || a == -b || a == I b || a == -I b) /. {Or -> Times,
    Equal -> Subtract} // Expand

Out[18]= a^4 - b^4
```

---

**EDIT**

In response to making the transformation leave out parts in other variables, one can write `Or` transformation function, and use in `Simplify`:

```
In[41]:= Clear[OrCombine];
OrCombine[Verbatim[Or][e__Equal]] := Module[{g},
  g = GatherBy[{e}, Variables[Subtract @@ #] &];
  Apply[Or, 
   Function[
     h, ((Times @@ (h /. {Equal -> Subtract})) // Expand) == 0] /@ g]
  ]

In[43]:= OrCombine[(a == b || a == -b || a == I b || a == -I b || 
   c == d)]

Out[43]= a^4 - b^4 == 0 || c - d == 0
```

Alternatively:

```
In[40]:= Simplify[(a == b || a == -b || a == I b || a == -I b || 
   c == d), TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, OrCombine}]

Out[40]= a^4 == b^4 || c == d
```

Comment: Nice, similar to Daniel's but different too. The result isn't an equation anymore, though.

Comment: I think Daniel and I offered essentially the same solutions, independently. Equality in mine is trivially obtained by equating the resulting polynomial to zero.

Comment: Although this is a solution for the problem exactly as I stated it, the solution should not harm other, non-related cases.  For example, `(a == b || a == -b || a == I b || a == -I b || c == d) /. {Or -> Times, Equal -> Subtract} // Expand` should be `a^4 == b^4 || c ==d`, not a^4 c - b^4 c - a^4 d + b^4 d`.

Comment: or at least something like `a^4 == b^4 || c == d`.

Comment: While both answers are good, I am picking this answer as the correct one because of the slight advantage that the result is still a logical expression.

Answer (score 11):

Could convert set of possibilities to a product that must equal zero.

```
expr = a == b || a == -b || a == I*b || a == -I*b;
eqn = Apply[Times, Apply[Subtract, expr, 1]] == 0

Out[30]= (a - b)*(a - I*b)*(a + I*b)*(a + b) == 0
```

Now simplify that.

```
Simplify[eqn]

Out[32]= a^4 == b^4
```

Daniel Lichtblau